# Dynamic importing of module yields empty object in NextJS SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-import

So I am trying to use this library [penumbra](https://github.com/transcend-io/penumbra) in a NextJS project. After adding it as a dependency, NextJS will throw an error that window is undefined, which makes sense since it's server-side rendering things and [penumbra](https://github.com/transcend-io/penumbra) uses unsafe access to the window object.

This is a common problem in NextJS and the goto solution is to use dynamic imports as documented [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

I tried this approach and the returned result is an empty object:

```
import("@transcend-io/penumbra").then(mod => {
  console.log(mod.default); // empty object, default export
  console.log(mod.penumbra); // undefined, named export
})
```

The weird thing is that this works with other modules say `moment` for example:

```
import("moment").then(mod => {
  console.log(mod.default()); // returns moment object
})
```

This leads me to believe that either I am missing something or the module itself is problematic.

Here is a [working NextJS example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-xpofcw?file=pages/index.js). If you check the logs, moment returns a moment object, but penumbra returns {} for default export and undefined for the named one.

Comment: I am not sure you found your solution or not but for me your code snippet work in case of importing third party module at root of application. Thanks :)